# Modify nth nested property in object

Tags: javascript, object, recursion, nested, logic

This is basically logic question that should apply in any programming language, i just happen to be using JavaScript for this

Basically imagine i have some kind of object like

```
{Props:"stuff", 
    other: {
        stuff: "etc",
        other: {
            Extra: "filler",
            other: {}
        }
    }
}
```

Essentially, the is an object with some unknown amount of extra properties, but every sub object has a single nested property with the same name "in this case "other"), and the depth could be infinite, meaning there could be an n number of objects inside the root object, with each sub object being container within another object who's key is the same (again in this case "other")

It may sound more complicated than it is but basically the property other is nested and repeated within the root object

The thing is i want to be make a function to break this nested chain at a given depth amount (n), thereby setting all of the further nested objects to one value

That might have sounded complicated but basically, in the above example, the object has a nested depth of the "other" property of 3, let's say i want to break the depth at depth index 2, thereby changing the object to only have one nested "other" property, set to some value (like a number or string, say "5" for example), instead of being set to yet another object that also contains the other property (as well as potentially additional properties etc)

So how can i make a function that takes in a base object, containing an unknown amount of nested properties Ruth key `k`, and cause it to return a new object (or modify the original, but i would prefer just returning a new one) that is almost identical to the base object, except that at depth index `n`, the nested property with key `k` will be set to value `v`, instead of continuing in it's chain of an unknown additional amount of nested depth

I can't even fathom how to do this, i always just go back to setting the property with index `k` equal to the root function, but passing the property itself as a parameter in place of the original root object (basically recursion) except if the input object does not contain The property `k`, in which case only the property itself is returned, but this is just a recursive method to return the innermost nested property, but in at a loss fit what to do to achieve the above mentioned result, which is, again, a new object almost identical to the base object Ruth the exception of it's nested property with key `k` at depth `n` being set to value `v`, im just at a complete loss as to where to even start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a recursive function here like this

```js
let obj = {Props:"stuff", 
    other: {
        stuff: "etc",
        other: {
            Extra: "filler",
            other: {
                stuff: "abc",
                other:{
                    stuff: "acbh",
                    other: {}
                }
            }
        }
    }
};

function normalizeObjectDepth(obj, level, curr_level, key){
    if(curr_level==level-1){
        obj.other = key;
        return;
    }
    normalizeObjectDepth(obj.other, level, curr_level+1, key);
}

normalizeObjectDepth(obj, 3, 0, 5);

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create recursive function with `reduce` method that will check if the current level of recursion is smaller then the target one and based on that continue with recursion or set the value to the desired one.

```js
const data = {
  Props: "stuff",
  other: {
    stuff: "etc",
    other: {
      Extra: "filler",
      other: {}
    }
  }
}

function modify(obj, key, lvl, val, clvl = 0) {
  return Object.entries(obj).reduce((r, [k, v]) => {
    if (k === key) {
      if (clvl < lvl) {
        r[k] = modify(v, key, lvl, val, clvl + 1)
      } else {
        r[k] = val
      }
    } else {
      r[k] = v;
    }

    return r;
  }, {})
}

const result = modify(data, 'other', 2, 'my value');
console.log(result)
```

Solution with plain `for...in` loop.

```js
const data = {
  Props: "stuff",
  other: {
    stuff: "etc",
    other: {
      Extra: "filler",
      other: {
        random: 'foo',
        other: 'random'
      }
    }
  }
}

function modify(obj, key, lvl, val, clvl = 0) {
  const result = {}

  for (let k in obj) {
    if (k === key) {
      if (clvl < lvl) {
        result[k] = modify(obj[k], key, lvl, val, clvl + 1)
      } else {
        result[k] = val
      }
    } else {
      result[k] = obj[k]
    }
  }

  return result

}

const result = modify(data, 'other', 2, 'random');
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thanks although i should have mentioned i want to keep this as low level as possible without using any ready to go methods including reduce, just basic for loops, variable increments and function calls essentially

Comment: @bluejayke I updated my answer with `for...in` loop solution

Answer (score 1):

This ensures a deep clone so the original object isn't changed. The only "high level" part is JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(...)), but that can be replaced by any method of deep copy, or you can simply deep copy before using function

```
const modifyNthKey = (obj, key, value, n) => {
  let i = 0
  let newObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))
  let tmpObj = newObj
  while (i < n) {
    console.log('typeof: ' + typeof tmpObj[`${key}`])
    if (typeof tmpObj[`${key}`] !== 'object') {
      throw Error('unable to access key. Parent not object')
    }
    tmpObj = tmpObj[`${key}`]
    i++
  }

  tmpObj[`${key}`] = value
  return newObj
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fairly simple recursive version.  It doesn't mutate your input, but returns a new structure:

```js
const modify = (obj, key, value, depth) => ({
  ...obj, 
  [key]: depth <= 0 ? value : modify (obj [key], key, value, depth - 1)
})

const data = {Props: "stuff", other: {stuff: "etc", other: {Extra: "filler", other: {}}}}

console .log (modify (data, 'other', 'new value', 2))
//~> {Props: "stuff", other: {stuff: "etc", other: {Extra: "filler", other:"new value"}}}

console .log (modify (data, 'other', 'new value', 1))
//~> {Props: "stuff", other: {stuff: "etc", other: "new value"}}

console .log (modify (data, 'other', 'new value', 0))
//~> {Props: "stuff", other: "new value"}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

Essentially we just copy the object, setting the target property (`'other'`) to either the new value (if we're at the end of the recursion, when `depth` is 0) or to result of a recursive call using `object[key]` and `depth -1` (otherwise.)

Note that we do not do a full clone, so other nodes might be shared by reference.